# Conditional statement in beamer style file

Tags: beamer, conditionals, frame-title

Here is an example of a part of a beamer style file I use for a presentation:

```
{
\nointerlineskip%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6cm,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{frametitle}
\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle}\textcolor{color1}{\insertframesubtitle}}\hfill \strut\par
\usebeamerfont{headline}%
\vskip.5ex
\end{beamercolorbox}
\nointerlineskip
\insertvrule{0.8pt}{black}
}
```

I would like to create a conditional statement based on the content of `\framesubtitle`, something like:

```
if \frametitle empty (or not defined)
  % do something
else
  % do this other thing
    {
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6cm,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle}\textcolor{color1}{\insertframesubtitle}}\hfill \strut\par
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \vskip.5ex
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \nointerlineskip
    \insertvrule{0.8pt}{black}
    }
end
```

I tried to use the `\@ifempty` command but I could not figure a way to make it work... Would you have any idea on how to deal with this efficiently ?

Comment: If no `\framesubtitle` command is given in a frame, `\insertframesubtitle` is equivalent to `\@empty`, so you might try `\ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty<code for no subtitle>\else<code for subtitle>\fi` Don't use braces around the code for the true and false parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by egreg gave me the answer I was looking for, thanks ! In the end, the code looks like:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{smoothtree theme}{
    \nointerlineskip%
    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6cm,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{frametitle}
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle}\textcolor{color1}{\insertframesubtitle}}\hfill \strut\par%
        \usebeamerfont{headline}%
        \vskip.5ex
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \else
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6cm,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{frametitle}
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle}\textcolor{color1}{\insertframesubtitle}}\hfill \strut\par%
        \usebeamerfont{headline}%
        \vskip.5ex
        \end{beamercolorbox}%   
    \fi
    \nointerlineskip
    \insertvrule{0.8pt}{black}}
```

And I can modify the part of the code after `\else` at will...